# Remove Scrolling up when end loading page

Tags: javascript, php

when i open my site, And scroll down of the page, At this time the site still loading. when finished loading.
The site scroll me up of the page.

I need to remove this option. How can do that.

Comment: Use a different browser, this isn't code related

Comment: yes its for all browser